# Default value for method parameter is not considered

Tags: scala, methods, default-value

I've supplied default values for the parameter "currentStack" in the "Empty" caseobject aswell as in the "Top" case class, but if I ommit the parameter when calling the push method I get the following message

```
"error: not enough arguments for method push: (newTop
: A, currentStack: Main.Stack[A])Main.Stack[A].
Unspecified value parameter currentStack.
                    currentBracket == '{') isBracketingValid(rest, bracketStack.push(currentBracket))".
```

I've tried constructing an empty stack aswell as an already filled one and called the push method on them it worked for adding one element. As soon as I tried to add another element with a further push call I get the above error message.

```
lazy val s1 = Empty

println(s1.push(1)) // <- works

//println(s1.push(1).push(2)) <- doesn't work

lazy val s2 = Top(3, Top(4, Empty))

println(s2.push(1)) // <- works

//println(s2.push(1).push(2)) <- doesn't work
```

here the Stack definition:

```
sealed trait Stack[+A] {
    def push[A] (newTop: A, currentStack: Stack[A]): Stack[A] = ???

    def pop: (Option[A], Stack[A]) = ???
}

case object Empty extends Stack[Nothing] {
    override def push[A] (newTop: A, currentStack: Stack[A] = Empty): Stack[A] = Top(newTop, currentStack)

    override def pop: (Option[Nothing], Stack[Nothing]) = (None, Empty)
}

case class Top[A](val top: A, val rest: Stack[A]) extends Stack[A] {
    override def push[A] (newTop: A, currentStack: Stack[A] = Top(top, rest)): Stack[A] = Top(newTop, currentStack)

    override def pop: (Option[A], Stack[A]) = (Some(top), rest)
}

def isBracketingValid(bracketString: String): Boolean = {
    def isBracketingValid(bracketList: List[Char], bracketStack: Stack[Char]): Boolean = bracketList match {
        case Nil => bracketStack == Empty
        case currentBracket :: rest => {
            lazy val previousBracket = bracketStack.pop._1.getOrElse('$')

            lazy val isRestValid = isBracketingValid(rest, bracketStack.pop._2)

            if (currentBracket == '(' ||
                currentBracket == '[' ||
                currentBracket == '{') isBracketingValid(rest, bracketStack.push(currentBracket))
            else if (currentBracket == ')') previousBracket == '(' && isRestValid
            else if (currentBracket == ']') previousBracket == '[' && isRestValid
            else if (currentBracket == '}') previousBracket == '{' && isRestValid
            else false
        }
    }
    isBracketingValid(bracketString.toList, Empty)
}
```

**EDIT**

rewritten the Stack definition after Luis's hint to use "this", so no it  doesn't cause the aformentioned problem as no stack is passed in, but I'm still interested in understanding the cause.

```
sealed trait Stack[+A] {
    def push[A] (newTop: A): Top[A] = ???

    def pop: (Option[A], Stack[A]) = ???
}

case object Empty extends Stack[Nothing] {
    override def push[A] (newTop: A): Top[A] = Top(newTop, this)

    override def pop: (Option[Nothing], Stack[Nothing]) = (None, Empty)
}

case class Top[A](val top: A, val rest: Stack[A]) extends Stack[A] {
    override def push[A] (newTop: A): Top[A] = Top(newTop, this.asInstanceOf[Stack[A]])

    override def pop: (Option[A], Stack[A]) = (Some(top), rest)
}
```

**EDIT 2**

refactored the stack defintion thanks to the insight of Luis to not use "asInstanceof" but accomplish the goal with a lower type bound instead. And also checked about why case clases should in general be final.

```
sealed trait Stack[+A] {
    def push[B >: A] (newTop: B): Top[B] = ???

    def pop: (Option[A], Stack[A]) = ???
}

case object Empty extends Stack[Nothing] {
    override def push[A] (newTop: A): Top[A] = Top(newTop, this)

    override def pop: (Option[Nothing], Stack[Nothing]) = (None, Empty)
}

final case class Top[+A] (val top: A, val rest: Stack[A]) extends Stack[A] {
    override def push[B >: A] (newTop: B): Top[B] = Top(newTop, this)

    override def pop: (Option[A], Stack[A]) = (Some(top), rest)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass a `Stack` to a `Stack` method?

Comment: To construct a new Stack, and thus make sure that the one on which the method is called remains unchanged.

Comment: I still do not get it. You always want `this`, and you return a new one, which shares this one. Since, your **Stack** is _immutable_, that wont be a problem. It is just like a normal **List**.

Comment: Thx for the hint of using the "this" keyword the code is much simpler now and the problem of course goes away if it is rewritten like this, but I would still like to understand the cause.

Comment: You should not use `asInstanceOf` almost never _(and if you are learning, you should assume it does not exists)_. You can rewrite like this `override def push[B >: A](newTop: B): Stack[B] = Top(newTop, this)` _(Also, you should mark your `Top` class covariant in A too. - `final case class Top[+A] ...`)_. -  Now, the problem was that, even if your two overrides had defaults, the method on the trait itself did not have it, and that was the one you were calling.

Comment: I see, since I'm passing in a Stack[Char]. It worked with the original Stack implementation after applying pattern matching. Hmm, I wonder if pattern matching is the correct approach in case of subtype dependent default values.Thank you for the answer and the insight. I've refactored the Stack definition accordingly. Could you please post the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, summarizing. The problem was that, even if in your two sub-classes, you had overridden the `push` method to had a default value.
The method signature on the **trait** did not have such default. And, since that was the one you were calling, the compiler emitted the proper error.
You could had done pattern matching, to know which specific *case* of `Stack` did you had, and that way the compiler would had found the signature with the default value. However, since the default was always a `Stack` with the same shape as **this**, and since what you really needed was to just use **this** *(since as an immutable collection, you can have structural sharing)*, it was better to just rewrite the method.

Following is the implementation of your `Stack` that is more concise and simple *(IMHO)*.

```
sealed trait Stack[+A] {
  final def push[B >: A](newTop: B): Stack[B] =
    Top(newTop, this)

  final def pop: (Option[A], Stack[A]) = this match {
    case Top(top, rest) => (Some(top), rest)
    case Empty          => (None, Empty)
  }
}

final case class Top[+A](top: A, rest: Stack[A]) extends Stack[A]
case object Empty extends Stack[Nothing]
```

Comment: Thank you again for the answer and the extra guidance. There is a small error in the final version in the pop method the top needs to be inside of a Some() class.

Comment: @Mahmoud Right, fast copy and pasting, sorry. You are welcome.